poetry show outdated from source
I've two packages:

package1
package2

I'm installing it from my source:
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "mysource"
url = "https://example.com/mysource/simple/"
priority = "explicit"

pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
package1 = { version = "==2.0.2", source = "mysource" }
package2 = {version = "==0.2.0", source = "mysource"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "mysource"
url = "https://example.com/mysource/simple/"
priority = "explicit"

Both of these packages are also available in pypi.org
so when i run the following command to check for outdated packages I get incorrect output
$ poetry show --outdated
package1             2.0.2                     28.0.0 description of package
package2             0.2.0                     5.8.0  description of package

It compared the installed versions with the versions of pypi.org packages, which is incorrect.
I don't want to change the priority of my source to primary as that is taking too long to run.
How can I check for outdated packages which are installed from mysource?
Expectation is to match the version from mysource and not from pypi.org
$ poetry show --outdated
package1             2.0.2                     2.0.3 description of package
package2             0.2.0                     0.2.1  description of package

